# Remove references to the token {$dataArray} as it has been replaced by {found within $participants}

Tags: tokens

Not quite sure about the "{found within $participants}" part of the story.
How would it look in, say, `{if}` and `{foreach}` :

- `{if !empty($dataArray)}` becomes `{if !empty($participants)}` ?
- `{foreach from=$dataArray item=value key=priceset}` becomes `{foreach from=$participants item=value key=priceset}` (????)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a lack of ideas, suggested wokaround would be:

- restore the default template
- re-apply  customizations made, if any.